# How should I be using querySelector here?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create front-end SPA routing for a client, without a framework, using vanilla JavaScript. Ultimately, I want to click a link in a list element, update the iframe, and update the taskbar URL. However, I can't do any of that until I can use `.querySelector()` reliably. Below is a snippet with the HTML (which is fine as is) and the JS (which…isn't).

```js
document.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  () => {
    /**
     * DOM object declarations
     */

    // ID-labeled content
    const $nav = document.getElementById("nav");

    // Tabs
    let tabs = {};
    for (let tab in ["home", "about", "songs", "rates", "contact"]) {
      tabs[tab] = $nav.querySelector(tab);
    }

    /**
     * Routing logic
     *
     * Creates an event listener for each tab, which updates the iframe
     * content and the URL.
     */

    const routerCallback = (key) => {
      console.log(key);
    };

    for (let key in tabs) {
      const $tab = tabs[key];
      $tab.addEventListener("click", () => routerCallback(key));
    }
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';">
    <title>Karaoke</title>
    
    <script src=/static/js/routing.js></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <a class="home" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a class="about" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <li>About</li>
    </a>
    <a class="songs" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <li>Songs</li>
    </a>
    <a class="rates" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <li>Rates</li>
    </a>
    <a class="contact" href="javascript:void(0);">
      <li>Contact</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<iframe
  id="content"
  width="800"
  height="600"
  src="/iframe/home"
></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

This results in console errors. When I step through with the debugger, I notice the `$nav` variable gets populated at first, but then gets set to `null`. `tabs` depends on this, so it gets populated with `null` values, as well. How do I properly set these values?

Comment: I think your html is wrong, the links `<a` should be inside `li` tags, which are directly related to their parent `ul` tag, and not the other way around like you did. but otherwise the here your link tags are useless, you can advantageously replace it with a `data` attribute in each `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of `for...in` to iterate over the elements of an array.
2. Use `.` before the class name to select elements with a specified class.

```
let tabs = {};
for (let tab of ["home", "about", "songs", "rates", "contact"]) {
    tabs[tab] = $nav.querySelector('.' + tab);
}
```

Comment: Good, but I still get `Uncaught TypeError: $nav is null`.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy I can't reproduce that: https://jsfiddle.net/kyacrpq0/

Comment: It occurs in Chrome and Firefox, in both private and regular windows.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy Could you provide a [mre]? Does the JSFiddle above produce the error for you too?

Comment: I did that, and the callbacks worked without error. I think it had to do with @Mister Jojo's suggestion, in part with yours, Unmitigated.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpliest way to do that :

```js
document.querySelector('#nav').onclick = e =>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li[data-ref]')) return // ignore click elsewhere (spaces...)
  console.clear()
  console.log('set iframe to ->', e.target.dataset.ref)
  }
```

```css
#nav ul {
  list-style : none;
  padding    : 0;
  width      : 6em;
}
#nav ul li {
  background-color : #6dd9e7;
  margin-bottom    : .1em;
  padding          : .2em .4em;
  cursor           : pointer;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  background-color : #60b6c2;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li data-ref="home"    > Home    </li>   
    <li data-ref="about"   > About   </li>  
    <li data-ref="songs"   > Songs   </li>  
    <li data-ref="rates"   > Rates   </li>  
    <li data-ref="contact" > Contact </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

*simpler and lighter code to do the same thing => fewer errors ...*